# jQuery FadeTo causing pixelated text in IE8 when font-weight: bold

Tags: jquery, css, fadeto

I am fading out, and in a div:

```
$('.formErrors').fadeTo('fast', 0); 
$('.formErrors').fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

But when I do this in IE 8, it seems this bit of CSS:

```
.formErrors li { font-weight: bold; }
```

Is causing the text to come back quite distorted: (image below)

http://www.newmania.com/images/error.jpg

The HTML I am applying this to is:

```
<div class="formErrors">
There are errors in your submission. Please fix the following and try again:
<ul><li>Action is empty</li></ul>
</div>
```

It works fine in Firefox. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common solution is to define a background color, if you don't already have an image:
http://jsbin.com/axapa

```
.formErrors {background-color:white;}
```

Another option is to use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`: the animation is till ugly, but at least it ends up nicely: http://jsbin.com/aboxa

Comment: Thanks Kobi! The background colour solution works well. With fadeIn and fadeOut, the animation is more ugly than using the 2 fadeTo's, so I'll stick with them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: +1 helped me solve an issue with `PNG` having ugly non transparent bg on IE8.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for this solution again. Setting a background on my text div fixed this! Was stressing for a deadline too! Wish I could + some more ! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.fn.fadeIn = function(speed, callback) { 
return this.animate({opacity: 'show'}, speed, function() { 
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)  
        this.style.removeAttribute('filter');  
    if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) 
        callback();  
});
};
jQuery.fn.fadeOut = function(speed, callback) { 
return this.animate({opacity: 'hide'}, speed, function() { 
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)  
        this.style.removeAttribute('filter');  
    if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) 
        callback();  
});
};
jQuery.fn.fadeTo = function(speed,to,callback) { 
return this.animate({opacity: to}, speed, function() { 
    if (to == 1 && jQuery.browser.msie)  
        this.style.removeAttribute('filter');  
    if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) 
        callback();  
});
};
```

This code will override some fade properties in JQuery specific to IE. I was able to successfully get fadeTo to work properly in IE here: https://app.tekstme.com/signup/

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is really old but i found a simple solution. Using background was not applicable for my case because i had a complex background behind text whose background had to be transparent. Anyway I found this one working pretty well (css code to add):

```
.formErrors{position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using <!DOCTYPE html> fixed this issue for me in IE8. The text still looks blocky during the fade but afterwards it smoothes out